# one-liner - how to understand?

Tags: python

How can I understand about the following one-liner code?

```
vins = {(vin['txid'], vin['vout']) for tx in raw_transactions
                                        for vin in tx['vin'] if 'coinbase' not in vin}
```

---

Update 1

I'm testing the following.

```
vins = []
for tx in raw_transactions:
    for vin in tx['vin']:
        if 'coinbase' not in vin:
           vins.append(vin['txid'], vin['vout'])
```

---

Update 2

This is raw_transactions.

```
[
   {
      'txid':'6a31558eadfd4d71316d1f074794716a660d3ca431ac0fa939daf4a971c3edde',
      'vin':[
         {
            'vout':1,
            'txid':'3579a3219c071afccddc0f2ac725ad844f5f16f25b253109df6996e824ef9c59'
         }
      ],
      'vout':[
         {
            'value':0.02159592,
            'n':0
         },
         {
            'value':0.007462,
            'n':1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      'txid':'92719026074f1e4ff3ea51b49da1a60b31ddda82456b24d70590276a5465687d',
      'vin':[
         {
            'vout':0,
            'txid':'6a31558eadfd4d71316d1f074794716a660d3ca431ac0fa939daf4a971c3edde',
         }
      ],
      'vout':[
         {
            'value':0.00226,
            'n':0
         },
         {
            'value':0.01481592,
            'n':1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: What is `raw_transactions`?

Comment: @martineau It's a set comprehension.

Comment: @chepner: Right...silly me. Thanks!

Comment: @S.G.Harmonia sorry I'm rate. I added an example raw_transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's constructing a `set` of `tuple` values. Here's a non-one-liner version:

```
vins = set()
for tx in raw_transactions:
    for vin in tx['vin']:
        if 'coinbase' not in vin:
            vins.add((vin['txid'], vin['vout']))
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood it. I got 'dict' object has no attribute 'add' error but I'm looking into it.

Comment: Glad to hear that...and you're right about getting the error, I was confusing `vin` and `vins`, which are two separate variables. Fixed that in updated answer.